# How to start Drawer Layout below the toolbar in Android?

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

Here is my main xml file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.example.amit.rssreader.MainActivity">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
            android:layout_gravity="start">

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is what is happening
[image: This is what is happening]

I want to have the drawer below the Action bar .This wasnt a navigation Drawer Activity, the navigation drawer has been added later by xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you:

1. Modify the xml layout:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
       </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

       <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
           <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent">
               <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
           </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
       </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Create theme for activity without toolbar in values/styles.xml and apply it to your activity in AndroidManifest file:

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. And to make it working, make the onCreate method of your activity to look like this:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) 
           findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

       ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
       if(supportActionBar != null) {
           supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
           supportActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
       }

       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       final ListView drawerList = (ListView) 
           findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
           drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
           new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" } ));



           drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

           ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle =
           new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                   toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);

           actionBarDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerList)) {
                   drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
               } else {
                   drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerList);
               }
           }
       });

       drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

       actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
   }
   ```

   And this is how does it work.
   [image: Drawer closed][image: Drawer opened]